# setting image of PictureBox[i] System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, arrays, image, visual-studio

Im currently making a game in Visual Studio 2017 C# I want to publish on the Windows Store but now I have an issue with setting an image of a PictureBox[] list Item and cannot find a solution or another way to set a image for all PictureBox List Items...

Here's my code:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TheSnakeGame
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SpielfeldEcke1.Location = new Point(0,100);
            SpielfeldEcke2.Location = new Point(this.Size.Width-SpielfeldEcke2.Size.Width,100);
            SpielfeldEcke3.Location = new Point(0,this.Size.Height-SpielfeldEcke3.Size.Height);
            SpielfeldEcke4.Location = new Point(this.Size.Width-SpielfeldEcke4.Size.Width, this.Size.Height - SpielfeldEcke4.Size.Height);

            int AnzahlGrenzeWidth = this.Size.Width-SpielfeldEcke1.Size.Width-SpielfeldEcke2.Size.Width;
            PictureBox[] GrenzlinieHorizontal1 = new PictureBox[AnzahlGrenzeWidth];
            for (int i = 0; i < AnzahlGrenzeWidth; i++) {
                GrenzlinieHorizontal1[i].Image = Image.FromFile(@"Bilder\BorderHorizontal.jpg"); ---- ERROR: System.NullReferenceException: "Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt."

                GrenzlinieHorizontal1[i].Location = new Point(SpielfeldEcke1.Size.Width+1+i,SpielfeldEcke1.Location.Y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please I need your help!

Comment: GrenzlinieHorizontal1[i].Image is null, you have to create a PictureBox before setting the image

Comment: Sure you can publish a Winfroms application in the windows store?

Comment: Ok I‘ll try adding GrenzlinieHorizontal[i] = new PictureBox();

Comment: Ok that worked but now the pictureBoxes I set are'nt visible

Comment: @MichaelPfister Well yes, you need to actually add them to the form, just like any control. What are you actually trying to do with an array of picture boxes? It seems like you're drawing a border with them, which doesn't seem like the kind of thing to use picture boxes for...

Comment: I already found out, but thx anyways (*^^)v

Comment: I tried to use this list for ingame borders, because I didn’t know that you could also generate the images in C# with System.Drawing. I made an image with the size of 1 px width and 10 px height for the upper border and tried to duplicate them with the screen length.